# Is there built-in excel functions that can check for: "10" (or any number) in "1,3,5-9,13,16-20,23"?

Tags: excel, count

As mentioned in the title, I wonder if there is any way to use built-in functions in excel to see whether a cell contains a specific number and count the total numbers in the cell. The cell can contain a list of numbers seperated by comas, for instance, "1,4,7" or ranges "10-25" or a combination of both. See the print screen.

[image]

Comment: No there is not a built in function of combination of functions that will do this outside 
 of maybe the new LAMBDA.   I say "maybe" because if it is it is beyond me.  But definitely not possible with any other standard formula.

Comment: You could use VBA or Power Query

Comment: I guess you could split it on comma with filterxml then split again on hyphen, something on those lines

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not, but you could [write a VBA function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f) to do that, something like:

```vb
Function NumberInValues(number As String, values As String) As Boolean
    Dim n As Integer
    n = CInt(number)
    
    Dim parts() As String
    parts = Split(values, ",")
    For i = LBound(parts) To UBound(parts)
        parts(i) = Replace(parts(i), " ", "")
    Next
    
    Dim p() As String
    Dim first As Integer
    Dim last As Integer
    Dim tmp As Integer
    
    For i = LBound(parts) To UBound(parts)
        p = Split(parts(i), "-")
        ' If there is only one entry, check for equality:
        If UBound(p) - LBound(p) = 0 Then
            If n = CInt(p(LBound(p))) Then
                NumberInValues = True
                Exit Function
            End If
            
        Else
            ' Check against the range of values: assumes the entry is first-last, does not
            ' check for last > first.
            first = CInt(p(LBound(p)))
            last = CInt(p(UBound(p)))
                                
            If n >= first And n <= last Then
                NumberInValues = True
                Exit Function
            End If
                
        End If
        
    Next
    
    NumberInValues = False
    
End Function
```

and then your cell C2 would be

```
=NumberInValues(B2,A2)
```

Calculating how many numbers there are in the ranges would be more complicated as numbers and ranges could overlap.

Answer (score 2):

The key part of implementing this is to create a List or Array of individual numbers that includes all the Numbers represented in the first column.

Once that is done, it is trivial to check for an included, or do a count.

This VBA routine returns a list of the numbers

```
Option Explicit
Function createNumberList(s)
    Dim AL As Object
    Dim v, w, x, y, I As Long
    
Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

v = Split(s, ",")
For Each w In v

'If you need to avoid duplicate entries in the array
'uncomment the If Not lines below and remove the terminal double-quote

    If IsNumeric(w) Then
        'If Not AL.contains(w) Then _"
        AL.Add CLng(w)
    Else
        x = Split(w, "-")
        For I = x(0) To x(1)
            'If Not AL.contains(I) Then _"
            AL.Add I
        Next I
    End If
Next w
createNumberList = AL.toarray
End Function
```

**IF** your numeric ranges might be overlapping, you will need to create a Unique array.  You can do that by changing the `AL.Add` function to first check if the number is contained in the list.  In the code above, you can see instructions for that modification.

You can then use this UDF in your table:

```
C2: =OR($B2=createNumberList($A2))
D2: =COUNT(createNumberList($A2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible formula solution using filterxml as suggested in the comment:

```
=LET(split,FILTERXML("<s><t>+"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</t><t>+")&"</t></s>","//s/t"),
leftn,LEFT(split,FIND("-",split&"-")-1),
rightn,IFERROR(RIGHT(split,LEN(split)-FIND("-",split)),leftn),
SUM(rightn-leftn+1))
```

The columns from F onwards show the steps for the string in A2. I had to put plus signs in because Excel converted a substring like "10-15" etc. into a date as usual.

Then to find if a number (in C2 say) is present:

```
=LET(split,FILTERXML("<s><t>+"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</t><t>+")&"</t></s>","//s/t"),
leftn,LEFT(split,FIND("-",split&"-")-1),
rightn,IFERROR(RIGHT(split,LEN(split)-FIND("-",split)),leftn),
SUM((--leftn<=C2)*(--rightn>=C2))>0)
```

[image]

As noted by @Ron Rosenfeld, it's possible that there may be duplication within the list: the Count formula would be susceptible to double counting in this case, but the Check (to see if a number was in the list) would give the correct result. So the assumptions are:

(1) No duplication (I think it would be fairly straightforward to *check* for duplication, but less easy to correct it)

(2) No range in wrong order like 15-10 (although this could easily be fixed by putting ABS around the subtraction in the first formula).

---

Here is a little cheeky piece of code for a VBA solution:

```
Function pageCount(s As String)


s = Replace(s, ",", ",A")

s = Replace(s, "-", ":A")

s = "A" & s

' s now looks like a list of ranges e.g. "1,2-3" would give "A1,A2:A3"

pageCount = Union(Range(s), Range(s)).Count


End Function
```

because after all the ranges in the question behave exactly like Excel ranges don't they?

and for inclusion (of a single page)

```
Function includes(s As String, m As String) As Boolean

Dim isect As Range
    
s = Replace(s, ",", ",A")

s = Replace(s, "-", ":A")

s = "A" & s

Set isect = Application.Intersect(Range(s), Range("A" & m))

includes = Not (isect Is Nothing)

End Function
```

Comment: G'damn, that's impressive! Thank you!!! I tried to build my own solution using built-in formulas but I gave up when I realised it would be one billion "characters" long.

Comment: Thanks Karl! Kind of on the cusp between formula and VBA I guess.