# Check if date ranges overlap within the same cell Excel 365

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a way to see if date ranges that are in the same cell overlap.  I have tried a `SUMPRODUCT` formula approach, but it doesn't seem to work as the start and end dates aren't separated.  The number of dates for each row can vary and there isn't a good way in my data to be able to list the start/end dates in separate columns on multiple lines for each record.

Example (all in one cell in Excel workbook):

```
4/20/2021 - 5/21/2021, 4/20/2021 - 5/20/2021, 4/26/2021 - 4/27/2021, 4/29/2021 - 5/4/2021
```

Comment: By "overlap" do you mean that there is some time point that falls within **all of the ranges** within a cell (all ranges mutually overlap)? One do you mean there is some time point that falls within **at least two ranges** within a cell (at least two ranges overlap)? Or something else?

Comment: If at least 2 date ranges overlap, then it would "count" as overlapping for what I'm needing.  The number of date ranges in each cell can change, one cell might only have 2 dates, the next cell could have 5 dates, so I am needing something that could handle that as well.  I hope that this helps clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67474457/is-there-built-in-excel-functions-that-can-check-for-10-or-any-number-in-1/67477941#67477941) and can be solved in the same sort of way by splitting on commas and then on hyphens, then checking for any overlaps:

```
=LET(Split,FILTERXML("<s><t>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</t><t>")&"</t></s>","//s/t"),
Ncomp,COUNTA(Split)-1,
Left,LEFT(Split,FIND("-",Split&"-")-1),
Right,RIGHT(Split,LEN(Split)-FIND("-",Split)),
Lsort,SORT(DATEVALUE(Left)),
Rsort,SORTBY(DATEVALUE(Right),DATEVALUE(Left)),
Lstart,INDEX(Lsort,SEQUENCE(Ncomp,1,2)),
Rend,INDEX(Rsort,SEQUENCE(Ncomp,1,1)),
(SUM(--(Rend>=Lstart))))
```

[image]

Columns B-J show the working broken down into stages and the final result using the combined 'Let' formula is in column K. I had to change the dates to DD/MM/YYYY so I can use Datevalue in my locale.

Comment: Thank you for the solution!  Is this the only way to be able to do this?  I have nearly 20,000 lines that I'll need to do this for and was hoping for a way to not have to split the date ranges up.  If it's not possible, I understand, but just wanted to see.

Comment: I don't think you can get much simpler than this with a formula - at least it's a single formula that you can pull down (the intermediate columns are just for explanation). The alternative is to use VBA which in some ways is easier.

Comment: I see now, sorry for my misunderstanding.  It looks like I don't have the availability to use the LET function just yet, but was able to make it work for my problem.  I appreciate your help!